# When can I be sure that object is proper initialized, e.g. if init() is called before other methods?

Tags: angularjs

```
function SomeService(Restangular) {
  var promiseConf = getConf();

  function getConf() { // get from database
    return Restangular.all('conf').getList().then(function(conf) {
      return conf; 
    })
  }

  function getConfObject() {
    return promiseConf.then(confArr => {
      return _(confArr).keyBy('myConf').value();
    });
  }
}
```

Now, in many of my controllers in `init()` method I do:

```
this.config = null;

init () {
    ...
    this.SomeService.getConfObject().then(conf => {
        this.config = do some thing with conf
    });
    ...
}

methodA () {
    // Can I be sure that in this place this.config is initialized from databse ?
}
```

The question is: Can I be sure that all methods are invoked after `init()` ?
In other words config all methods requires `this.config` to be initialized.
If I can't assume it, how to reach this effect ? Keep in mind my code.

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks

Comment: I did read it, but I am not sure If I correctly understand. Could you answer to my specific question to make it clear for me ?

Comment: Rather than have your own init() method called from the constructor, use $onInit()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.then` method of a promise returns a new promise that can be used for chaining:

```
this.config = null;

init () {

    this.configPromise = this.SomeService.getConfObject()
      .then(conf => {
        this.config =  conf;
        return this.config;
    });

}
```

By saving the promise returned, code that depends on the asynchronous data can [chain](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#chaining-promises) from that promise:

```
methodA () {

    // Can I be sure that in this place this.config 
    // is initialized from databse ?

    this.configPromise.then(config => {
        //Put code that depends on valid config here
    };
}
```

Comment: I can't understand you. Your `methodA` is in the same controller class as `init`. You refer in `methodA` to `this.configPromise....`. After all, you don't define it in class. Maybe some magic of javascript ? And second thing. What about saving information. What in case if config is some constant which should be fetchted from database only once (to reduce transfer) ? Could you refer to these two question, please ?

Comment: Read [You're Missing the Point of Promises](https://blog.domenic.me/youre-missing-the-point-of-promises/). If the promise is saved, it can be accessed many times without making another XHR request to the server.

Comment: What about first question ?

Comment: JavaScript is not a class-based object-oriented language. It is a functional language with objects that use prototype-based inheritance. What ES6 calls classes is syntactic sugar that mimics classes. Properties and methods can be added and [removed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete) from objects in JavaScript.

Comment: Could you check again if `getConfObject` and `getConf` will co-operate with you sample code ? As I told, I must by sure. Mainly it is about `then`

Answer (score 0):

> // Can I be sure that in this place this.config is initialized from
>   databse ?

No.

> If I can't assume it, how to reach this effect ? Keep in mind my code.

Several ways to achieve this. You can use 'resolve' or you can define abstract parent state to all your states, and have template:

```
<ui-view ng-if="configLoaded"></ui-view>
```

Then in child states you can be sure that config request completed.

Comment: Is it sufficient to add such `ng-if="configLoaded` in components (so two templates) which usr this `config` ?

Comment: This all depends on what you exactly want. Imagine this request take 10 min - what you want to show? Some waiting page? Then you add ng-if on entire view. Or you want to block only part of view and show loading indicator near some button...